# pyqt5 GUI looks different in raspberry pi than in QtCreator/Windows (again)

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have seen [pyqt5 GUI looks different in raspberry pi than in QtCreator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51582044/pyqt5-gui-looks-different-in-raspberry-pi-than-in-qtcreator) - but there is no reproducible example there, so below is the .ui code I got from QtDesigner 5.6.2 running on Windows 10, and the corresponding .py file that I run under Python 3.

The answer recommended there, `QApplication.setStyle("fusion")`, seems to fix most of my problems - the only problem remaining is that some texts on the Raspberry Pi are in a font that is much larger, than on the version rendered on windows. Note that this example uses Arial font, and under Raspbian Stretch, I have installed Arial via `sudo apt install ttf-mscorefonts-installer`; and `fc-list | grep -i arial` shows it is installed.

So, this is how the layout looks like in QtDesigner (click for full-size image):

[image: test_qtdesigner_pyqt5_01]

... this is how it looks under Python3/PyQt5 in MINGW64 on Windows 10:

[image: test_qtdesigner_pyqt5_02]

... and this is how it looks under Python3/PyQt5 in Raspbian 9 (Stretch) - note that if you view this under a VNC connection with few colors, the gray app background will actually appear pink! (you will have to grab a screenshot with `scrot` to see what the actual colors are):

[image: test_qtdesigner_pyqt5_03]

As it can be seen, the only remaining obvious difference, is the font size of the button and the label texts.

How can I ensure that layout is the same in both Windows and Raspberry Pi PyQt5 - which for this specific case, means how to get the font size of the labels/buttons the same?

*** test_qtdesigner_pyqt5.py ***

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
import os

# NOTE: to get Arial etc on Raspbian 9 (Stretch): `sudo apt install ttf-mscorefonts-installer` (installs: cabextract libmspack0 ttf-mscorefonts-installer)

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui, uic
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot

UI_PATH = "./test_qtdesigner_pyqt5.ui"

import platform


# NOTE: default geometry/size of window is: [(0, 0), 854 x 600]
class TestMainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow): #, Ui_MainWindow):
  newPointProcessed = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)

  def __init__(self):
    super(TestMainWindow, self).__init__()
    uic.loadUi(UI_PATH, self)

    # simulate the layoutLeftMargin/Top/Right/Bottom of centralwidget as in QtDesigner
    self.centralwidget.setContentsMargins(9,9,9,9)

    self.main_horizontal_splitter.setSizes([200, 600]) # good enough for startup layout

    self.show()

  def exitCleanUp(self):
    print("'{}' has exited.".format(window.windowTitle()))


if __name__ == "__main__":
  QtWidgets.QApplication.setStyle("fusion")
  app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
  window = TestMainWindow()
  window.show()
  app.aboutToQuit.connect(window.exitCleanUp) # SO:18732894
  sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

*** test_qtdesigner_pyqt5.ui ***

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>854</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="font">
   <font>
    <family>Arial</family>
   </font>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Testing QtDesigner PyQt5</string>
  </property>
  <property name="styleSheet">
   <string notr="true"/>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <property name="font">
    <font>
     <family>Arial</family>
    </font>
   </property>
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
    <item row="0" column="0">
     <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="topmost_vertical_layout" stretch="0,1">
      <property name="spacing">
       <number>6</number>
      </property>
      <item>
       <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="header_vertical_layout">
        <item>
         <widget class="QLabel" name="title_label">
          <property name="font">
           <font>
            <family>Arial</family>
            <pointsize>18</pointsize>
           </font>
          </property>
          <property name="text">
           <string>Testing QtDesigner PyQt5</string>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </item>
       </layout>
      </item>
      <item>
       <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="main_horizontal_layout">
        <item>
         <widget class="QSplitter" name="main_horizontal_splitter">
          <property name="sizePolicy">
           <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Preferred">
            <horstretch>0</horstretch>
            <verstretch>2</verstretch>
           </sizepolicy>
          </property>
          <property name="font">
           <font>
            <family>Arial</family>
           </font>
          </property>
          <property name="orientation">
           <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
          </property>
          <widget class="QFrame" name="frame_01_test">
           <property name="font">
            <font>
             <family>Arial</family>
            </font>
           </property>
           <property name="frameShape">
            <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
           </property>
           <property name="frameShadow">
            <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
           </property>
           <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="vertical_layout_01">
            <item>
             <widget class="QPushButton" name="btn_test">
              <property name="font">
               <font>
                <family>Arial</family>
               </font>
              </property>
              <property name="text">
               <string>Test button</string>
              </property>
             </widget>
            </item>
            <item>
             <widget class="QLabel" name="lbl_test">
              <property name="font">
               <font>
                <family>Arial</family>
               </font>
              </property>
              <property name="text">
               <string>Test list below:</string>
              </property>
             </widget>
            </item>
            <item>
             <widget class="QListView" name="list_test">
              <property name="font">
               <font>
                <family>Arial</family>
                <weight>75</weight>
                <bold>true</bold>
               </font>
              </property>
             </widget>
            </item>
           </layout>
          </widget>
          <widget class="QFrame" name="frame_02_details">
           <property name="font">
            <font>
             <family>Arial</family>
            </font>
           </property>
           <property name="frameShape">
            <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
           </property>
           <property name="frameShadow">
            <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
           </property>
           <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="vertical_layout_02"/>
          </widget>
         </widget>
        </item>
       </layout>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>854</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="font">
    <font>
     <family>Arial</family>
     <weight>75</weight>
     <bold>true</bold>
    </font>
   </property>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17332224/8512134 try reading here

Comment: Thanks @Kendoka - that answer makes sense, as reading through the `.ui` XML, I see that QtDesigner does not enter/record the `pointsize` if it is the same as the default, which for me is 8. However, it does not work for me: I tried `defaultfont = QtGui.QFont('Arial', 8); defaultfont.setPixelSize(8); QtWidgets.QApplication.setStyle("fusion"); app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv); app.setFont(defaultfont); app.font().setPixelSize(8)` - and the text size of the label/button on Raspbian is still the same as in OP screenshot. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this turned out to be more complicated than I expected.

As per the comment by @Kendoka, I took a look at [Qt fonts have different sizes on different systems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17320263/qt-fonts-have-different-sizes-on-different-systems/17332224#17332224) :

> I have encountered a similar problem. In our case it had to do with the local Linux font settings. And since we couldn't force all computers in the world to use the same font we override the font in our application.
>
> ```
> QFont _Font("Tahoma", 8);
> QApplication::setFont(_Font);
> ```
>
> You should do this before your main window is created.

So, I tried this in main:

```python
if __name__ == "__main__":
  defaultfont = QtGui.QFont('Arial', 8)
  defaultfont.setPixelSize(8)
  QtWidgets.QApplication.setStyle("fusion")
  QtWidgets.QApplication.setFont(defaultfont)
  app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
  app.setFont(defaultfont)
  app.font().setPixelSize(8) 
  ...
```

... and it didn't work - fonts on Raspbian were the same as in the OP screenshot.

First, I noticed that if you do `.setPixelSize(8)`, then it turns out PyQt5 sets `.pointSize()` and `.pointSizeF()` to -1, and vice versa. So, one has to settle for either point size, or pixel size, for fonts.

Then, I found:

https://forum.qt.io/topic/76023/applicationwindow-font-not-changed-by-qguiapplication-setfont

> From the ApplicationWindow documentation, it says that the "font" property can be changed by setting the QGuiApplication font prior to loading the QML.

So I got interested in this piece of documentation, and it is here:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#setFont

> Warning: Do not use this function in conjunction with Qt Style Sheets. The font of an application can be customized using the "font" style sheet property. To set a bold font for all QPushButtons, set the application styleSheet() as "QPushButton { font: bold }"

So, it is quite possible this kind of QtDesigner application defaults to using style sheets, and thus ignored `QtWidgets.QApplication.setFont(defaultfont)` (or `app.setFont(defaultfont)`). But then, further on in the thread:

https://forum.qt.io/topic/76023/applicationwindow-font-not-changed-by-qguiapplication-setfont

> > Oh, so in addition to calling QApplication::setFont(), you can call qmainwindow->setFont(), and that's enough? Thanks, I'll try that.
>
> Well in QML if I set the font to the `ApplicationWindow` then yes all elements that were not well handling the `setFont` are now using the right one.

Right - so I tried that, and finally it worked:

```python
if __name__ == "__main__":
  defaultfont = QtGui.QFont('Arial', 8)
  QtWidgets.QApplication.setStyle("fusion")
  QtWidgets.QApplication.setFont(defaultfont)
  app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
  app.setFont(defaultfont)
  window = TestMainWindow()
  window.setFont(defaultfont) # THIS finally changes the font!
  window.show()
  app.aboutToQuit.connect(window.exitCleanUp) # SO:18732894
  sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Can't really tell if `QtWidgets.QApplication.setFont` and `app.setFont` are completely irrelevant, but I guess it does not hurt to keep them there for reference ...